# Angular - Página sem mostrar componentes anteriores

Tags: html, angular, aplicação-web, typescript, angular-cli

Sou novo no angular, acostumado com o href do HTML e simplesmente abrir outra página, vamos ao problema!

1 - Tenho um formulário pedindo o nome e um botão de submit

2 - Tenho um outro componente que é simplesmente um parágrafo com um título comum: 'Minha segunda pagina'

Quando eu clicar no botão, ele fosse pra essa segunda página, mas o que acontece é que ele mostra na mesma página, usando router-outlet, como é single page, não sei se é necessário esconder o formulário ou apenas redirecionar, tudo o que eu faço ele apenas mostra na mesma página após o router, alguém pode me ajudar?

Era clicar no botão e mostrar só o título e sumir o formulário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente você esta utilizando o `<router-outlet>` dentro da componente do formulário. Coloque o formulário em uma componente separada sem o `<router-outlet>`.

Deixe o `<router-outlet>` somente para `AppComponente` ou componente que sirvam de template. Como sua outra página já esta componentizada, é de se esperar que a estrutura do seu projeto fique assim:

```
app.component.ts
    |- formulario
        |-formulario.component.ts
        |-formulario.component.html
    |-outra-pagina
        |-outra-pagina.component.ts
        |-outra-pagina.component.html
```

Comment: Isso, está desse mesmo jeito, a questão é que quando clico no botão, ele não some os componentes antigos, simplesmente abre embaixo da tag, gostaria que quando clicasse sumisse os componentes antigos e aparecesse a outra página.

Comment: Por favor, poste o código então do seu `routing` e o `html` da página do form

Answer (score 0):

Quando tu abre o componente na tela o componente deve mesmo ficar na tela, 
pra redirecionar para outra tela tem algumas maneiras( estas são as que eu me lembro de cabeça, pode haver muitas mais).

Pra redirecionar no html tem essa maneira:
podes colocar dentro de um

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-small" [routerLink]="['/produtos/modelos/' + item.idProduto]">Ver Modelos</a>
```

Ou ate mesmo usar um metodo no TS que chame o Router.
Coloca no contrutor:

```
private router: Router
```

depois pra redirecionar faz isso

```
this.router.navigate(['/produtos/modelos/', id]);
```

se quiser dar uma olhadinha em @ViewChild é muito bom pra quem está iniciando,
o site do angular tem muita informação, sempre bom dar uma olhada( https://angular.io/docs ) e também tem o curso da Loiane Groner  no youtube, é gratis.

Comment: Eu estou usando o this.router.navigate(['/home/']); Só que, quando clico no botão, ele aparece embaixo, e os componentes de cima não somem, a dúvida é se realmente preciso esconder, ou tem alguma forma de rotear, pra quando eu clicar que navegar, sumir todos os antigos e mostrar apenas o novo.